# Cron job in Laravel 5.6 to send email with a generated PDF file

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, dompdf

I have a question about how to method. I'm using Laravel
The goal : 
Send an email the last day of month with a generated PDF.

How can you do to achieve this ?

I create my PDF in controller like this (with laravel-dompdf package)

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('exportPDF.templatePDF', compact('data'));
return $pdf->stream('fileName'.pdf');
```

Should I use a notification file (*php artisan make:notification ActionNotification*) to add in my job queue ? A command file (*php artisan make:command ActionCmd*) ? Directly in the method in my Controller ? or other method ?

I'll appreciate that you give me the right way to develop this feature in Laravel.
Because I don't know how and where to start to do this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [Queued Job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#creating-jobs) and call it via [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling).
Like so:

```
php artisan make:job SendMonthlyEmailWithPDF
```

Then edit the `handle` method in the created class to send the email.
And to call it at every end of a month:

```
$schedule->job(new SendMonthlyEmailWithPDF)->when(function () {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much